# LINQ query using Group By and Let

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have the below table,

```
Name    Consumed
A   Flavour 1
B   Flavour 2
C   Flavour 1
C   Flavour 3
A   Flavour 3
B   Flavour 1
C   Flavour 3
A   Flavour 2
A   Flavour 1
C   Flavour 1
A   Flavour 1
B   Flavour 2
```

Where in the first column I have the name of the persons and in the second column the Flavour preferred by them. I want to generate the below table, with Flavours as columns and find the sum of the Flavours preferred by each person. I know the solution to these using SQL, however I'm looking for a solution using LINQ VB.Net.

```
Name  Flavour 1  Flavour 2  Flavour 3
A     3          1          1
B     1          2          0
C     2          0          2
```

SQL Query for achieving the above result,

```
SELECT Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Consumed='Flavour 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Flavour 1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Consumed='Flavour 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Flavour 2,
SUM(CASE WHEN Consumed='Flavour 3' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Flavour 3
GROUP BY Name
```

Below is the LINQ query,

```
Dim query = (From row In dtMain.AsEnumerable
             Let Flavour_1 = IIf(row.Field(Of String)("Consumed") = "1", 1, 0)
             Let Flavour_2 = IIf(row.Field(Of String)("Consumed") = "2", 1, 0)
             Let Flavour_3 = IIf(row.Field(Of String)("Consumed") = "3", 1, 0)
             Group row By Code = row.Field(Of String)("Name")
             Into freq = Group Select .Code = Code, .Count = freq.Count()).ToList
```

My difficulty is in how to aggregate the temporary variables Flavour_1, Flavour_2 and Flavour_3 using SUM function and group it by Name.

Comment: And what were your failing tries so far?

Comment: Same concept as SQL - group by name, count occurrences of each flavour.  Give it a shot and ask a specific question when you're stuck.

Comment: However I looking for the exact syntax to achieve the same using LINQ in VB.Net.

Comment: @AnandSeniyar: Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to do group bys in LINQ? Do you now know how to get the counts once they are grouped? Do you not know what LINQ is? At the moment you have stated your goal but not a problem for us to help you with.

Comment: I'm comfortable using Group By and LET statement in LINQ, however my difficulty is in achieving the  above result using the combination of Group By and LET statement.

Comment: @AnandSeniyar, if you're looking for somebody to write the linq code for you, you may be out of luck.  Why not give it a try and when you get stuck show what you tried?

Comment: @Smeegs: Sadly there is always somebody wanting the rep. :) Or maybe we are just being curmudgeonly (if that is the word I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following data:

```
Dim table = {
    New With { .Name = "A", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "B", .Consumed = "Flavor 2" }, 
    New With { .Name = "C", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "C", .Consumed = "Flavor 3" }, 
    New With { .Name = "A", .Consumed = "Flavor 3" }, 
    New With { .Name = "B", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "C", .Consumed = "Flavor 3" }, 
    New With { .Name = "A", .Consumed = "Flavor 2" }, 
    New With { .Name = "A", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "C", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "A", .Consumed = "Flavor 1" }, 
    New With { .Name = "B", .Consumed = "Flavor 2" }
}
```

the query you're looking for is:

```
Dim result = From e In table 
             Group e By Name = e.Name Into g = group
             Select New With 
             { 
                .Name = Name, 
                .Flavour1 = g.Count(Function(x) x.Consumed = "Flavor 1"), 
                .Flavour2 = g.Count(Function(x) x.Consumed = "Flavor 2"), 
                .Flavour3 = g.Count(Function(x) x.Consumed = "Flavor 3") 
             }
```

[image]

It's quite similar to your SQL (group, then aggregate), but you use `Count` instead of `SUM`.

You don't need a `Let`.